# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

I am doing an insert into a table and relying on the auto_increment to generate a unique ID, however on some random occasions it fails to do that, instead giving this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '121092752' for key 'PRIMARY'
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `audit_entry` (`route`, `request_method`, `created`) VALUES ('queue/listen', 'CLI', '2018-08-27 10:03:09')
```

The table is as follows:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE audit_entry\G
   Table: audit_entry
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `audit_entry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `duration` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_method` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ajax` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `route` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `memory_max` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `idx_route` (`route`),
  KEY `created` (`created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=121096793 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The version of mysql:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION()\G
VERSION(): 5.5.59-38.11-log
```

The server that encountered this issue is configured to be a slave to another server (in a 2-server-daisy chain).  It has `server_id=2` and `auto_increment_offset=2`.  The other server has `server_id=3` and `auto_increment_offset=3`.  Both have `auto_increment_increment=10`.

As an aside, when this occurred the server was experiencing much higher than average load.

Comment: This is a hypothesis, not an answer. Sounds like you can run into this if you get a collision between the master and slave databases' autoincrement value when you have inserts going on on both servers at once. Try enclosing the insert in a transaction. You can roll back and retry if you get the duplicate key error.

Comment: The purpose of  `auto_increment_increment` is to set these to two different values on each server ( 1 & 2). Do you have this? Are writing to both server at the same time? Is this error occurring in the replication stream? What binlog_format are you using?

Comment: @danblack sorry I mixed up offset/increment when creating the question.  Have updated with my actual settings.